how to get keyboard focus while not be activated in windows

when I type in clipboard management software， the text editor window is still active and the cursor is blinking.
How can I implement this feature in my own clipboard management software using QT.
a gif demonstrating the operation of the windows built-in clipboard management software in a text editor (because stackoverflow has some problem with gif file. so I use a link, click link first then click picture to play gif)

For QML you can use forceActiveFocus().

You'd want to check out QTextEdit's focusOutEvent (the other editors have the same event override), which can be overridden to prevent the cursor from being hidden.
void MyTextEdit::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event) // QTextEdit derived class
{
    const Qt::FocusReason r = event->reason();
    if (r == Qt::PopupFocusReason)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        QTextEdit::focusOutEvent(event); // Retains normal QTextEdit behavior
    }
}

This code will only keep the cursor visible if the reason for the loss of focus is that you opened a popup (a QWindow class with the Qt::Popup flag set).
Keep in mind that this function will not prevent the change of focus, only what happens to this specific class when it does.

The text editor is not my applicaiton. It can be any texteditor.

@yiC Ah, I misunderstood, I thought you meant the other way around. In that case, I do not know. I imagine one of two options: Either an OS API call to maintain focus on one element while keyboard events gets sent to another, or you'll have to fake a focus in your app by stealing global key events. Neither of which I can help with.
This Github repo might serve as inspiration?

thanks. the repo is not the thing i describe. My question needs someone who is very good at windows development.
